# Custom QML component with a ScrollView+TextArea: TextArea not scrollable correctly

Tags: qt, scroll, qml, textarea

I have a custom QML component I'd like to use for text editing. When I add it to my main application, scrolling is very... "broken": the scrollbar doesn't reflect the right height of the content and shrinks in size when I scroll. When I get to the bottom of the sample text (10 paragraphs), it jumps back up to the top. What could be wrong?

[image]

[Reproducible test case Qt project](https://transfer.sh/xLj2e/buggy-scrollview-textarea.zip). Both QML files replicated below:

Custom widget (`Instance.qml`):

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ScrollView {
    property string myText

    clip: true
    contentHeight: height
    ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

    TextArea {
        id: textArea
        text: myText
        selectByMouse: true
        wrapMode: "WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere"
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering

        background: Rectangle {
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "black"
        }
    }
}
```

`main.qml`:

```js
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        id: errorsColumn
        anchors.fill: parent

        ScrollView {
            id: errorsScrollView
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            clip: true

            contentWidth: parent.width
            contentHeight: errorsRepeaterColumn.height

            Column {
                id: errorsRepeaterColumn
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                spacing: 5

                add: Transition {
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; easing.type: Easing.OutBounce; duration: 500 }
                }

                Repeater {
                    model: 10
                    Button {
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.maximumHeight: 300
                        text: "I'm item " + index

                        onClicked: resultsPageEditor.state = "VISIBLE"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        InstanceEditor {
            id: resultsPageEditor
            myText: "1 Numquam ducimus facilis quo eum perspiciatis sint alias soluta. Sit cupiditate dolorem perspiciatis quia fugit. Voluptas molestiae eius molestiae. Dolorum ipsam ipsum corporis provident nobis.

2 In assumenda suscipit incidunt et quas vero dicta. Ut et dolorem aut. Odio quo eveniet aut soluta harum molestias cumque vel. Nisi quis sed quaerat sapiente eos quaerat qui et. Numquam delectus ad delectus.

3 Enim rem et nihil nobis omnis voluptatem odit sed. Nemo rerum autem ipsa quia non quia. Praesentium molestiae iusto modi sint. Qui laboriosam eum quaerat aut cum perspiciatis. Qui iusto quisquam aut assumenda velit excepturi fugit rerum.

4 Veritatis est ut inventore sed eos. Dolorem perferendis mollitia illum vel dignissimos est. Iste explicabo quidem est.

5 Qui ad qui omnis molestias occaecati dolorum. Corrupti fuga voluptatibus voluptas laboriosam libero et sit. Omnis sed ut quia animi rerum voluptatem. Totam et impedit consequatur excepturi minus. Optio voluptatibus cumque neque sit blanditiis.

6 Autem quam laborum aut illum non nam eius debitis. Dolorem nostrum et molestiae eos. Dolorum architecto praesentium dignissimos corporis dignissimos.

7 Repudiandae autem autem animi. Praesentium exercitationem voluptate fugit voluptas cum voluptas. Perferendis eos aut modi corporis ratione et rerum.

8 Exercitationem amet itaque hic voluptas sunt hic eaque asperiores. Rerum corporis iure placeat possimus dolorem. Aut esse tempora odio quo provident laboriosam ut aut. Quam natus vero iusto qui quia qui ad. Quas quos vitae adipisci consequatur.

9 Perferendis inventore voluptas distinctio. Aspernatur sit magnam mollitia doloribus eum. Temporibus aut sunt nihil perferendis quisquam quidem tempora. Magni quia nihil sequi.

10 Est rerum et illum. Repellendus cumque aut voluptate qui omnis rem. Ut optio amet eius. Nemo ex et voluptatem adipisci dolorem molestiae. Maxime sint sint dolorem ut reiciendis sed dolor modi. Ipsa perferendis recusandae laboriosam."
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 0

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "HIDDEN"
                    PropertyChanges { target: resultsPageEditor; height: 0 }
                },
                State {
                    name: "VISIBLE"
                    PropertyChanges { target: resultsPageEditor; height: 250 }
                }
            ]
            state: "HIDDEN"

            transitions: [
                Transition {
                    from: "*"; to: "VISIBLE"
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "height"; easing.type: Easing.InBack; duration: 500 }
                },
                Transition {
                    from: "*"; to: "HIDDEN"
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "height"; easing.type: Easing.InBack; duration: 500 }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let the `ScrollView` manages the content size. The second problem is that you put the `Instance` in a layout. You should use `implicitHeight` to handle the size of your item.

This should work as you want:

```
Instance {
            id: resultsPageEditor
            myText: "1 Numquam ducimus facilis quo eum perspiciatis sint alias soluta. Sit cupiditate dolorem perspiciatis quia fugit. Voluptas molestiae eius molestiae. Dolorum ipsam ipsum corporis provident nobis.

2 In assumenda suscipit incidunt et quas vero dicta. Ut et dolorem aut. Odio quo eveniet aut soluta harum molestias cumque vel. Nisi quis sed quaerat sapiente eos quaerat qui et. Numquam delectus ad delectus.

3 Enim rem et nihil nobis omnis voluptatem odit sed. Nemo rerum autem ipsa quia non quia. Praesentium molestiae iusto modi sint. Qui laboriosam eum quaerat aut cum perspiciatis. Qui iusto quisquam aut assumenda velit excepturi fugit rerum.

4 Veritatis est ut inventore sed eos. Dolorem perferendis mollitia illum vel dignissimos est. Iste explicabo quidem est.

5 Qui ad qui omnis molestias occaecati dolorum. Corrupti fuga voluptatibus voluptas laboriosam libero et sit. Omnis sed ut quia animi rerum voluptatem. Totam et impedit consequatur excepturi minus. Optio voluptatibus cumque neque sit blanditiis.

6 Autem quam laborum aut illum non nam eius debitis. Dolorem nostrum et molestiae eos. Dolorum architecto praesentium dignissimos corporis dignissimos.

7 Repudiandae autem autem animi. Praesentium exercitationem voluptate fugit voluptas cum voluptas. Perferendis eos aut modi corporis ratione et rerum.

8 Exercitationem amet itaque hic voluptas sunt hic eaque asperiores. Rerum corporis iure placeat possimus dolorem. Aut esse tempora odio quo provident laboriosam ut aut. Quam natus vero iusto qui quia qui ad. Quas quos vitae adipisci consequatur.

9 Perferendis inventore voluptas distinctio. Aspernatur sit magnam mollitia doloribus eum. Temporibus aut sunt nihil perferendis quisquam quidem tempora. Magni quia nihil sequi.

10 Est rerum et illum. Repellendus cumque aut voluptate qui omnis rem. Ut optio amet eius. Nemo ex et voluptatem adipisci dolorem molestiae. Maxime sint sint dolorem ut reiciendis sed dolor modi. Ipsa perferendis recusandae laboriosam."
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "HIDDEN"
                    PropertyChanges { target: resultsPageEditor; implicitHeight: 0; }
                },
                State {
                    name: "VISIBLE"
                    PropertyChanges { target: resultsPageEditor; implicitHeight: 250; }
                }
            ]
            state: "HIDDEN"

            transitions: [
                Transition {
                    from: "*"; to: "VISIBLE"
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "implicitHeight"; easing.type: Easing.InBack; duration: 500 }
                },
                Transition {
                    from: "*"; to: "HIDDEN"
                    NumberAnimation { properties: "implicitHeight"; easing.type: Easing.InBack; duration: 500 }
                }
            ]
        }
```

```
ScrollView {
    property string myText

    clip: true
    ScrollBar.vertical.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn

    onImplicitHeightChanged: textArea.update()

    TextArea {
        id: textArea
        text: myText
        selectByMouse: true
        wrapMode: "WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere"
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering

        background: Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "black"
            color: "red"
        }
    }
}
```

In MacOS, I saw that the content of the `TextArea` is not displayed correctly when the `ScrollView` is resized. That's why I put the line `onImplicitHeightChanged: textArea.update()`. But, it's working fine without it on my Linux.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!